# Crystal Reports size/position formula fails in production

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that positions an image object based on a calculation like this:

```
formula = ((59 * {TABLE;1.SCORE}) - 230)
```

It works beautifully on my local machine, but when I move it to a production server, the objects don't change position (they remain at their start position).

I've tried both Crystal and VB syntax.  I added a formula field that shows that the calculation is working as expected.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You should support you question by providing some code.

Comment: There is code.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Based on tests in a development server environment, it turns out is was versioning problems.  With the correct runtime, the positioning works.  I'm trying to upgrade the version of CR runtime on the server, and if I can ever get past the install errors, that should fix it.

Update:  Upgrading the server to the latest CR runtime resolved the problem.